# Insert if not exists with Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql

I am encountering the following problem I am trying to insert data into the table if 
phone, sushi_service_id both has a row with active = 1
for example:

```
ID | Phone | sushi_service_id | active
---------------------------------------
1  | 455   | 1                | 1 (LEGAL)
3  | 455   | 1                | 0 (LEGAL)
4  | 455   | 1                | 0 (LEGAL)
5  | 455   | 1                | 1  (NOT LEGAL! HAS THE SAME PHONE+SUSHI_SERVICE_ID+ACTIVE=1)
```

This is my codeigniter code:
how can I improve it in order to work like I said above?

```
public function add($service, $phone, $sushi_subscription_id, $answer_id, $affiliate_id, $ip, $query, $invite_type, $invite_msg_id)
{

    $this->db->set('service_id', $service->id);
    $this->db->set('sushi_service_id', $service->sushi_service_id);
    $this->db->set('phone', $phone);

    if ($sushi_subscription_id) {
        $this->db->set('sushi_subscription_id', $sushi_subscription_id);
    }

    $this->db->set('answer_id', $answer_id);
    if ($affiliate_id) {
        $this->db->set('affiliate_id', $affiliate_id);
    }

    $this->db->set('added', 'NOW()', FALSE);

    $this->db->set('active', 1);
    $this->db->set('ip', $ip);

    $this->db->set('query', $query);

    if ($invite_type) {
        $this->db->set('invite_type', $invite_type);
    }

    if ($invite_msg_id) {
        $this->db->set('invite_msg_id', $invite_msg_id);
    }

    return ($this->db->insert($this->_table_name)) ? $this->db->insert_id() : FALSE;
}
```

Comment: [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) ?

Comment: @Dainis Abols: You should read the existing answers before writing a comment. it is not considered a a duplicate if it the fiels is not declared as unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just do a `select * from XX where active = 1` and then based on the result of `num_rows` the insert query.

Comment: done that, but its not working when theres a double press on the button which sends this query.

Comment: Double press? This is the right solution, you just have to implement it correctly.

Comment: What you mean with double press? Of course it works. otherwise you do something wrong. Its unlogical that it doe snot work on a double press since the num_rows is still correct. If it returns `1` you do the insert query otherwise not.

Answer (score -2):

Easiest way to do this would be in a single INSERT with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE query.

Example structure:

```
INSERT INTO table ... VALUES .... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
```

Comment: what if its not a unique key? as you can see phone,active=0 and sushi_service_id can be infinite amount of times

Comment: It's not technically a duplicate key though since multiple values are allowed if it's not active.

Comment: As i know it has to be unique, otherwise this is not going to work.

Comment: Fair point, I missed that. In that case I'd suggest Michael's solution.